# Any way to dump JavaFX FXML UI as a static HTML page?

Tags: html, javafx, fxml

We are building a JavaFX desktop app which is made themeable from the get-go with external CSS files. Now we'd like to give our designers (who are not programmers) some opportunity to tweak the look of the app without having to install JFX, NetBeans and restart the app each time.

Is there some way to dump the static FXML look of the UI as a HTML file of some sort? Basically so that the designer can tweak the CSS and refresh the look with F5.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the Scene Builder supports CSS, so there should be no need to transform FXML to HTML.

Otherwise you could write a XSL script or a Java programm (e.g. using StAX) to do the transformation, but that would be quite a bit of work, I guess.